# How do you create a class, or function in python that allows you to make a sequence type with specific characteristics

Tags: python

1) My goal is to create a sequence that is a list that contains ordered dictionaries. The only problem for me will be described below.

- I want the list to represent a bunch of "points" which are for all intents and purposes just an ordered dictionary. However, I notice that when I use OrderedDict class, when I print the dictionary it comes up as OrderedDict([key value pair 1, key value pair 2, ... etc)] For me, I would rather it behave like an ordered dictionary, BUT not having those DOUBLE "messy/ugly" "end marks" which are the "[( )]". I don't mind if the points have ONE, and only one, type of "end marks". Also I would also like it if when I print this data type that stuff like `OrderedDict()` doesn't show up. However, I do not mind if it shows up in return values. Like you know how when you print a list it doesn't show up as `list(index0, index1, ... etc)` but instead it shows up as `[index0, index1, ... etc]`. That is what I mean. Inside the point, it would look like this

`point = {'height': 1, 'weight': 3, 'age': 5, etc}` <- It could be brackets or braces or parentheses. Just some type of "end mark", but I preferably would like it to be in {} and having key value pairs indicated by key: value and have them separated by commas.

what_i_am_looking_for = `[point0, point1, point2, point3, ... etc]`

Comment: Is the printed representation really that important for you? If I may ask, why?

Comment: Because I am planning on having not just ONE point or even one list of points, but like a bunch like less than 100 but more than like 3. So if I look at them, I would rather not be bothered by so many "start/end marks" It just makes it harder to look at.

Comment: why don't you just write a function to print your list of ordered dicts however you want?

Comment: I would, but the "OrderedDict([]) just is like really bothering me. I even would be okay with just NameOfSequence{} where NameOfSequence{} behaves like an OrderedDict. Like if I have 10 "point lists" I would like it to not strain my eyes. I know I probably sound petty, but using OrderedDict for multiple lists is sort of hard for me to look at (differentiate between the entire point and the key value pairs).

Comment: Right, so again, why don't you just write a function to print it however you want?

Comment: Like: `insides = ', '.join([str(dict(x)) for x in  data]); print(f'[{insides}]')`

Comment: I guess I could try that

Comment: `def pretty_print(data): print(f"[{', '.join([str(dict(x)) for x in data])}]")` and then use it to print your lists

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.6, the ordinary `dict` implementation was re-written and maintains key insertion order like `OrderedDict`, but was considered an implementation detail. Python 3.7 made this feature an official part of the language spec, so if you use Python 3.6+ just use `dict` instead of `OrderedDict` if you don't care about backward-compatibility with Python 3.5 or earlier.